# Type mismatch in trait bound - Why can't rustc infer the type on its own?

Tags: rust

I just ran into an issue in some code of mine and managed to trim it down to the following minimal example :

```
use std::iter::IntoIterator;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Bar<'a> {
    fn compile_plz(&self) -> &'a str;
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    ph: PhantomData<&'a str>
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn compile_plz(&self) -> &'a str {
        "thx"
    }
}

fn do_something_with_bars<'a, I>(it: I) -> Result<(), ()> where I: IntoIterator<Item=&'a Bar<'a>> {
    Ok(())
}

fn take_bar<'a, B>(b: &'a B) where B: Bar<'a> {
    do_something_with_bars(vec![b]);
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo{ph: PhantomData};
    take_bar(&f);
}
```

This fails with the following error :

> 23:5: 23:27 error: type mismatch resolving `<collections::vec::Vec<&B> as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == &Bar<'_>`:
>   expected type parameter,
>      found trait Bar [E0271]

However, changing `vec![b]` to `vec![b as &Bar]` works fine. But since `b` is of type `&B`, and `B` has a `Bar<'a>` bound, why can't the compiler figure out that `b` is indeed a `&Bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could theoretically attempt to 'fix' the type to `&Bar`. However, you're hitting the variance problem here - a vector of `&B` is not a vector of `&Bar` just because a `&B` is a `&Bar`, and neither is the inverse true.

Example: Say we treat a vector of `&B` as a vector of `&Bar`. Now we have a value of type `&C` where `&C` is a `&Bar` but not a `&B` - can we put a `&C` into our vector? Well, obviously not, because the implementation is a vector of `&B`. So we can only allow reads, not writes. On the other hand, we can attempt to treat a vector of `&Bar` as a vector of `&B` - this works fine as long as we only write `&B`s into our vector (because it's allowed to accept `&B`s of course) - but since it's still a vector of `&Bar`, it can contain things that aren't `&B`s, so we aren't allowed to read from it.

Hence, a container that allows both read and write at the same time needs to be invariant in its generic argument. You'll always have this problems in languages that have both polymorphism *and* generics in this fashion.

So, back to the actual question: Since this problem exists, there can't be an automatic escape hatch that would turn your expression that is initially going to be inferred to be vector of `&B` to the type vector of `&Bar`. Be explicit about your types, and this won't happen.

---

Full type inference *maybe* could help here, but I'm not sure if full type inference is even possible in a language like rust.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. I expected the reason to be something along those lines but couldn't just put words on it.

Comment: "both polymorphism and generics" I'd say that it is better written as "both subtyping and generics" since generics are a kind of polymorphism (namely, the [parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) one).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Good point, but I'm imagining most people here are coming from a C++/Java background and understand 'polymorphism' to mean 'subtyping'; I don't think it makes the answer harder to read for the haskellers among us either though.